# Output voltage using Bode plot

Tags: voltage, frequency, 741-opamp

We have this circuit
[image]

And using the simulator I found the load voltage at the resistor 10 k ohm, based on different frequencies. And I got this curve at the Bode plot. where Y axis represents the voltage across the load ( resistor 10 k ohm in the picture) and x axis the frequency.
[image]

Using this plot I have to predict the Vout at frequency 10 k Hertz.
I know that the output voltage should be reduced by a factor of 104( 80 dB), so the output voltage would be 250 uV.

But I am not sure I fully understand why we should use this factor, and how we used it to get the result 250uV.

Comment: *Reduced by a factor of 104* means a gain of approximately -40dB.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming you meant that you use a 10k ohm load and want to know the Vout when input frequency is 10khz. Assuming this is the gain of the circuit plotted on the y-axis. You would look at the bode plot and pin point the 10khz frequency point on horizontal axis. Draw a vertical line at this point. Then find on the curve where This vertical line intersects the curve. At this point Vout=Vin*gain.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the y axis is the voltage across the load

Comment: Well in that case you would just see where the vertical line passes through curve and then you have Vout. Though let me ask, can you see the curve at 10khz?

Comment: Reason I ask is because it looks like the curve only goes down to like 5khz

Comment: No, I cannot thats why I was confused

Comment: So I got that curve by measuring the voltage at the Resistor Ri1. Is that the right resistor that I should have measure the voltage drop?

Comment: Well in this case, since you know it’s -80db/decade which is equivalent to -24db/octave  (ie -24db  per double frequency) since 20db/decade=6db/octave. And because you know what gain is at 5khz, you can use the rule that gain (in db) at 10khz =gain at 5khz -24db/octave

Comment: What are you trying to measure? vout of entire circuit or Output  of first circuit?

Comment: To get the curve I was measuring the voltage across the resistor Ri1. Using that curve I had to find the Vout of the entire circuit

Comment: You should be measuring the output marked Vout in your circuit. Voltage across Ri1 is a feedback voltage which isn’t what you really want.

Comment: Okay, Thank you !